# Possible to empty remove session value of a site using the logout button of the other site?

Tags: session, button, browser, logout, json-rpc

I have two sites(Site1, Site2). What I want to do is that when I click on the logout button of Site1, Site2 will also logout if it a user has logged in on that site on the same browser.

The solution is to remove the session. That is possible for Site1, but it doesn't work on Site2.

So, is it possible to remove session value of a Site2 using the logout the button of Site1? Or could be, is it possible to remove all sessions found in the browser?